# Google Analytics tag "fired" in GTM but no collect request

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've spent 3 nights testing, debugging and reading articles from Simo Ahava etc. with no success. Please advice, GA & GTM masters.

#### Situation

I have a page A which contains an iframe B with a 3rd party reservation form which contains an iframe C where my mesurement codes are separated.

```
+--My website A-------+
|                     |
|  +--Ext.iframe B-+  |
|  |               |  |
|  |  +-iframe C+  |  |
|  |  |         |  |  |
|  |  | My tags |  |  |
|  |  +---------+  |  |
|  |               |  |
|  +---------------+  |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

I'm sending tracking data via window.postMessage from `C` co `A`, so when users stays on my website `A`, it's ok.

But when a user finishes an order he's redirected to a thank you page under `B` which I can't modify (I can only add my own measurement codes as HTML to iframe `C`).

So I also put GTM to the iframe `C` and push purchase data into dataLayer. It seems fine, as seen in this picture:

[image: GA tags seem to be fired]

#### Problem

BUT the problem is **no GA `collect` HTTP request are called**, no real time data appears in GA3 o GA4. However, Facebook pixel does trigger a HTTP request so I assume the problem is not in GTM, but in GA.

#### FYI - I already tried

- There are a few 3rd party GA and GTM codes in page `B` (not under my control).
- I tried reseting cache, doesn't help.
- I tried using a standard direct implementation (not through GTM) to send the simplest event to GA4 or GA3 (both gtag and UA implementations), no data are sent.
- Below is pretty much the whole content of iframe `C` with my measurement codes (replaced identifiable info with XXX..).
- In iframe `C`, moving GTM init tag to the bottom doesn't help.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


<script>
    // data to send
    var gtmEvent = {
        event: "purchase",
        userData: {
            'email': "{email}",
            'phone': "{phone}"
        },
        ecommerce: {
            transaction_id: "{id}",
            value: {price},
            currency: "{currency}",
            items: [
                {
                    item_id: "{saleId}",
                    item_name: "{eventName}",
                    price: {price},
                    quantity: {count}
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    // for GTM in the same frame
    var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push(gtmEvent);

    // for GTM in host page (top parent)
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        i++;
        if (i > 30) {
            //console.log("clearing interval");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        try {
            var postObject = JSON.stringify(gtmEvent);
            parent.parent.postMessage(postObject, '*');
            parent.postMessage(postObject, '*');
            //console.log("message posted");
        } catch (e) {
            window.console && window.console.log(e);
        }
    }, 1000);       
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? Please post if you did.

Comment: I would also be interested in details about this! Did you @aic find out anything?